# I can't get my jQuery Event Listener to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Trying to set up an on click event listener for a submit button. Here is my jQuery code -

```
(function($) {
  console.log('working');

  $("#submit").on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('test');
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Here is the HTML -

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit Result" />
```

I'm doing this on a Word Press site. I know the .js file is linked correctly because I see the 'working' console log.

What is wrong with the code?

Edit -

Just tried this -

```
  $(window).on('click', function() {
    console.log('test');});
```

And that works. Is there an issue with how I have my ID set up in the HTML?

Comment: You need to use a document.ready event handler, not an IIFE. https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you wrote is fine. I assume you linked the Javascript file on the top of the page - which doesn't work out.

You have to add the `<script>` tag on the bottom of your html for it to work.

```
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit Result" />

    // Rest of HTML

    <script src="link/to/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 'jQuery' instead of '$' in WordPress to avoid conflict

```
(function(jQuery) {
  console.log('working');

  jQuery("#submit").on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('test');
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: The OP provides `jQuery` in to the IIFE. The `$` is already aliased.

Answer (score 0):

The submit button will still run the forms POST action.    You can hide the real submit button, and create a button to trigger the submit (usually after validation).

As for comments about $ and jQuery conflicts etc...  Using the encapsulation code below you should be fine to use either one.

```
<button id="preSubmit">Submit</button>
<input style="display:none;" type="submit" id="serverSubmit">

(function ($) {
    $(function () {  //document.ready

        $("#preSubmit").on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#serverSubmit").trigger("click");
        });     

    });
})(jQuery);
```